# String palindrome checker in java not working?

Tags: java, string, boolean, stringbuilder, palindrome

I am trying to write a program for these instructions:

> Given a string, determine if it is a palindrome, considering only alphanumeric characters and ignoring cases.
>   Note: For the purpose of this problem, we define empty `String` as valid palindrome.
>   https://leetcode.com/problems/valid-palindrome/

For some reason, the `.reverse()` in the last line doesn't reverse it. I've tried debugging by adding print statements and I see that the string DOES reverse earlier on. What is going on here? Please guide me!

```
public static boolean isPalindrome(String s) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
        if (Character.isLetter(s.charAt(i))) {
            sb.append(s.charAt(i));
        }
    }
    String x = sb.reverse().toString();
    System.out.println(x);
    if (sb.length() == 0) 
        return true;
    else 
        return sb.toString().equals(x);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that [`reverse()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#reverse()) changes the `StringBuilder` itself. So you are comparing the reverse, with the reverse again. Instead change your method to:

```
String x = sb.toString();
return sb.reverse().toString().equals(x);
```

Which will compare the `StringBuilder` *before* reversing, with the reversed `StringBuilder`. Note that the `if(sb.length == 0)` is not necessary, as if it is empty, `sb.reverse().toString().equals(x)` will still return true.

Also your search is case sensitive, when the problem statement says that it should match regardless of case. Change where you append to:

```
if (Character.isLetter(s.charAt(i))) {               
     sb.append(Character.toLowerCase(s.charAt(i)));
}
```

---

Also you can take advantage of `replaceAll` and `toLowerCase()` to shorten your method to:

```
public static boolean pali(String s) {
    String copy = s.toLowerCase().replaceAll("[^a-z]", "");
    return new StringBuilder(copy).reverse().toString().equals(copy);       
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because after first invocation of `sb.reverse()` sb has changed it state.